# Is there a way to set generated cookie from backend to front end using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, cookies, nestjs

Am trying to bring the generated cookie from the backend (nestjs) to front end (vuejs) but it failed to set on website. As shown below there is no cookie there
[image]

I tried using

```
headers:{

    "set-cookie" : "SESSION-COOKIE"
    
  }
```

But obviously it doesn't work as it is a forbidden header. The "SESSION-COOKIE" is the name of the cookie that has been set at the backend. Hope someone can help and do not hesitate to ask me question for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the backend is setting the cookies correctly, [here's the link](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies) to official NestJS documentation about cookies.

The value from the [set-cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header will just be stored by the browser, it's only forbidden to be accessed by the JavaScript, however so you should be able to see it in the Dev Tools.

In your case it looks like backend is not setting it in the right way.